# Rails 3.2. Override validates_presence_of behavior

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine

I'm writing a `Redmine` plugin and added some fields to `issues` form via `hooks` (the fields are also added to `Issue` table), so far so good. Now I want to make those fields mandatory, but can't figure out how to 'override' `validates_presence_of` behavior for `Issue` model.

I've created a hook for `Issue` save method, in order to check presence of my new fields before saving, but not sure if this is the best way to go. Is it possible to just extend `Issue` model so that it validates for presence of my new fields?

Comment: You can add in model validates :new_field :presence=> true

Comment: Thanks @Debadatt. I can't modify the original Issue model, is it possible to extend it to add that sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add validations on new fields in you plugin. Example is [here](https://github.com/twinslash/redmine_time_limit/blob/master/lib/redmine_time_limit/time_limit_time_entry_patch.rb)

```
# load plugin file(s)
Rails.configuration.to_prepare do
  TimeEntry.send(:include, TimeLimitTimeEntryPatch)
end



# in patch file
module TimeLimitTimeEntryPatch
  def self.included(base)

    base.send(:include, InstanceMethods)

    base.class_eval do
      unloadable

      validates_presence_of :comments
      validate :validate_time_limit_allowed_ip

    end

  end

  module InstanceMethods

    def validate_time_limit_allowed_ip
      # add error if permission is not set and IP is not allowed
      if !self.class.have_permissions?(user, project) && !time_limit_allowed_ip
        errors.add(:hours, I18n.t(:not_allowed_ip))
      end
    end

  end

end
```

Comment: Thanks so much @gotva, I was so close!

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively:

1) Create extension somewhere in your lib directory (make sure that it is `required`):

```
module IssueExtensions
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    validates_presence_of :new_attr
  end

end
```

2) Send it to `Issue` model. Good place for this could be `config/initializers/extensions.rb` (must be initialized after `Redmine` obviously):

```
Issue.send(:include, IssueExtensions)
```